# Cannot connect Postgres database with Spring Boot in docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running the following docker-compose on my vps to start up my stack which include a Postgres database and a Spring Boot api. Both are spun up in containers in the same network. Locally, I run the api separately (not in a container) while the database is ran in one, and the api is able to connect to it by specifying the port it exposes to the host.

Now, this docker-compose meant for production is a whole dilemma. What can I try next?

Here's my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
  api:
    image: ghcr.io/mycoolproject/apiproject:latest
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

Here's how I run it:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE="prod" \
            DATABASE_PORT="5233" \
            DATABASE_NAME="api-db" \
            DATABASE_USER="admin" \
            DATABASE_PASSWORD="admin123" \
            API_PORT="8080" \
            docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Here's my application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}

spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${DATABASE_NAME}
```

And here's the error I get: **(URL must start with 'jdbc')**

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' [...] Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Comment: What is DB on url section? Is it address of host?

Comment: Yes it's the database host. 

It's the db service in docker-compose, from my understanding, the name of services can be used as host inside the docker network. Seeing as both of my services in the same network, it makes sense for me to use the name as host

Comment: Maybe try to surround your url with quotes

Comment: My recommendation is to remove the network bridge, and to try basic first before introducing properties https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-postgresql-docker

Comment: Remove the bridge, if the error is still present, send the result of `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 1):

### Side remark

> (…) this docker-compose meant for production (…)

Beware, the lines

```
    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_PORT}:5432
```

are risky because it means the database will be reachable directly from the host.

This is unnecessary for the `api` service to reach the `db` service.

So, just remove this property if the configuration is intended for prod,
and add the following property in both services:

```
    networks:
      - app-network
```

### Suggestion for the main issue

It is difficult to suggest a direct fix for your issue because some info is lacking *and* the error looks fishy (it says *must start with 'jdbc'* while it already starts with 'jdbc').

So, just let me suggest an alternative, simpler design:

1. Use less environment variables to specify the database URL and **don't include the Java-specific `jdbc:` prefix.**
2. Create a `DataSource` class (→ rely on regular Java programming instead of a mere `application.properties` file), thus following some idea from [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic#configuring-a-datasource-bean).
3. And replace your `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE="prod" … docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` code with a simpler CLI command, with fewer variables and using `.env` files if need be.

Here is a complete setup example (under MIT license):

#### Step 1

> docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:13'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - app-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    image: ghcr.io/mycoolproject/apiproject:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      DATABASE_NO_SSL: "true"
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_POSTGRES_URL}
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - db
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  app-db:
    driver: local
```

> .env (containing sensitive values)

```yaml
# If you edit DATABASE_NAME or USER or PASSWORD, also edit DATABASE_POSTGRES_URL.
DATABASE_NAME = "mydb"
DATABASE_USER = "admin"
DATABASE_PASSWORD = "admin123"
DATABASE_POSTGRES_URL = "postgres://admin:admin123@db:5432/mydb"
# Here: db is the docker-compose service identifier & 5432 should always be 5432.
```

> .gitignore

```
.env
```

#### Step 2

> DataConfig.java

```java
package project.app;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@Configuration
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
        String DBURL = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL");
        String NOSSL = System.getenv("DATABASE_NO_SSL");
        if (DBURL != null && DBURL.length() > 0) {
            URI dbUri = new URI(DBURL);
            String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
            String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath()
                    + ("true".equals(NOSSL) ? "" : "?sslmode=require");
            System.err.println("*** DataConfig: jdbc:postgresql://_");
            DataSourceBuilder basicDataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            basicDataSource.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            basicDataSource.url(jdbcUrl);
            basicDataSource.username(username);
            basicDataSource.password(password);
            return basicDataSource.build();
        } else { // useful for in-memory test
            DataSourceBuilder basicDataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            basicDataSource.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:test";
            System.err.println("*** DataConfig: jdbc:h2:_");
            basicDataSource.url(jdbcUrl);
            basicDataSource.username("TODO");
            basicDataSource.password("");
            return basicDataSource.build();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 3

Just run:

```bash
docker compose config  # to check variables interpolation
docker compose up -d   # to run the stack
```

Indeed: `-f docker-compose.yml` is always unnecessary, and `DATABASE_USER="admin" …` is always parsed from the `.env` file.

Comment: Hi @Johni, did you get a chance to test the approach I suggested?